# How to attach my device with IOMMU framework?

Tags: linux-device-driver, x86-64, iommu

I'm adding IOMMU support in my linux driver and notice the IOMMU groups are assigned to the device during boot:

> [    0.942274] iommu: Adding device 0000:03:00.0 to group 28

Although, when I try to `iommu_attach_device()` inside the driver, it fails. I found it's failing when it calls `iommu_group_get()` for my device.

How do I get the assigned group for my device and use it inside my driver?
I'm using Ubuntu 4.15.0-45-generic kernel.

**Edit:**
`iommu_group_get()` fails when `struct device` field `iommu_group` is not initialized. Also, I'm manually loading the driver after boot.

**Edit2:**
I do see the device added to group 28 in dmesg output. I've the following sequence in my driver probe routine which I got by referring to existing kernel driver sources:

```
if iommu_present()
    iommu_domain_alloc(&pci_bus_type) 
    iommu_set_fault_handler() 
    group = iommu_group_get(); 
    // added group check since iommu_attach_device is failing 
    // group is NULL, was expecting group_28 
    iommu_attach_device() 
    init_iova_domain()
```

I've IOCTL calls for pinning the userspace virtual address (`get_user_pages_fast`) and performing `iommu_map`.  Is this valid for enabling DMA to the device using userspace region?

Comment: Which platform you are on?

Attaching to iommu is typically not driver's job but platform's. For device tree based platform, you should device iommu setup in device tree.

Comment: @NikitaYushchenko I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1. Yes, I do see the device added to `group 28` in `dmesg` output. I've the following sequence in my driver probe routine which I got by referring to existing kernel driver sources:

```
if iommu_present()
    iommu_domain_alloc(&pci_bus_type)
    iommu_set_fault_handler()
    group = iommu_group_get();  
    // added group check since iommu_attach_device is failing
    // group is NULL, was expecting group_28
    iommu_attach_device()
    init_iova_domain() 
```

Comment: @NikitaYushchenko I've IOCTL calls for pinning the userspace virtual address (`get_user_pages_fast`) and performing `iommu_map`.  The goal is to use this mapped space for DMA to device memory.

Comment: You do not need to explicitly bother with iommu. Just get pages, convert to scatterlist, dma_map_sg() and run you DMA. Platform will set up iommu transparently for you.

Comment: I am trying to do a direct DMA from the user allocated space to device. So, I want to setup iommu with a contiguous view of the DMA'able space  for the device.

Comment: To do that, just pin pages (get_user_pages*()), dma-map them (dma_map_sg()), and run DMA. Setting up iommu is not your driver's job.

Comment: Platform will set up iommu for you, that will happen inside dma_map_sg().

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Nikita, dma_map_sg in my case hangs the system with crash trace pointing to `intel_map_sg() -> domain_get_iommu()`. I'm using the following sequence:

`get_user_pages_fast() ;
sg_alloc_table_from_pages() ;
dma_map_sg()`.

Comment: Please post your entire source code and complete crash log.